# How to search based on custom attribute?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, attributes, directory-services

I have some special custom attributes with my ldap setup. I have a custom attribute called `GroupCode`. I have bunch of entries with this special attribute that I was able to write to the ldap database.

Lets say that I have one object with `GroupCode` attribute value `xyz` and another object with `GroupCode` attribute value `wasd`. I search with the filter `(GroupCode=xyz)` and `(GroupCode=wasd)` neither one of these search return anything. However, if I change the filter to `(GroupCode=*)`, then it would return all the entries that have the `GroupCode` attribute.

I have examined the attribute properties, and it looks normal, the apache directory studio shows it to be of `String` value, do I don't know why it isn't searching with the filter I provided. My knowledge with ldap structure is fairly limited, as it is fairly complex.

Anyone have any idea, please let me know. Much appreciated. Thanks.